# How can I retrieve the data inserted in a form from a Spring MVC method controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I am working on a Spring MVC application that use **Thymeleaf** as view technology.

So, in this view I have a form that is bound to a model object, something like this:

```
<form id="datiAinmatoreDigitale" th:object="${datiAnimatoreForm}" method="post" th:action="@{/salvaDatiAnagraficiAD}">
    <div class="row text-left rigaNominaAnimatoreDigitale">
        <div class="col-md-4 leftAlligned">
            <label for="nomeAD">Nome docente:</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 leftAlligned">
            <input id="nomeAD" class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{nome}"/>
        </div>
   </div>

   .............................................................
   .............................................................
   .............................................................
   SOME OTHER FIELDS
   .............................................................
   .............................................................
   .............................................................

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="color: #0F8BB0; margin-right: 10px;">Save</button>
</form>
```

As you can see when he user click on the **Save** button the form iss submitted with a POST request toward the **/salvaDatiAnagraficiAD** resource that is handled by this method defined into a controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/salvaDatiAnagraficiAD", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String salvaDatiAnagraficiAD(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Locale locale) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    System.out.println("INTO salvaDatiAnagraficiAD()");

    return "blablabla";

}
```

Ok, it works and I correctly enter into this **salvaDatiAnagraficiAD()** method when the form is submitted.

Now my problem is: how can I retrieve the data inserted into the previous form from my **salvaDatiAnagraficiAD()** controller method ?

I tryied to implement something like this (based on some code find in my project) but it can't work (an exception is thrown so I think that this is not the right way to do it):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/salvaDatiAnagraficiAD", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String salvaDatiAnagraficiAD(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Locale locale) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    System.out.println("INTO salvaDatiAnagraficiAD()");


    DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest) request;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    AnimatoreForm datiAnimatoreForm = mapper.readValue(multipartRequest.getParameterMap().get("form")[0], AnimatoreForm.class);

    return "blablabla";

}
```

What am I missing? How can I corretly retrieve the data inserted into my form and put these data into the **AnimatoreForm** object?

Comment: On mobile, but look at `@ModelAttribute`, which does all of that parsing for you and injects a full POJO as a method argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the annotation @RequestParam with a Map object in the method signutare.
Like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/salvaDatiAnagraficiAD", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String salvaDatiAnagraficiAD(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params, HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Locale locale) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
return null;}
```

In method-body you could access all parameters from form with

```
params.get("input-name");
```

In your example it would be

```
params.get("nome");
```

An other option is, that you use the object from the form in the controller-method signature

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/salvaDatiAnagraficiAD", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String salvaDatiAnagraficiAD(AnimatoreForm datiAnimatoreForm, HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Locale locale) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    return null;
}
```

So it's possible to access the input-fields with your object

```
datiAnimatoreForm.getNome();
```